# CSS Parent element not taking child height

Tags: html, css

I need one help to get a parent element to take the height of a child element. Code below.
3 sections. Section 2 is to set a slideshow but picture is overlapping  on other 2 sections.
Images are 1200 * 550px

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  flex-grow: 2;
  display: block;
}

.slideshow img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>The Header</h1>
    <section>
      <div class="slideshow">
        <!-- image size 1200 × 550 -->
        <img src="/images_server/image1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="/images_server/image2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <hr>
      <H1>New section</H1>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have your images set to `position: absolute`. That takes them out of the document flow and they will overlap all the other content on the page. There are plenty of slideshow tutorials/examples that can help you fix this.

Comment: Actually I want the parent(with a height set to auto) element to grow with the height of the child in a responsive way, thus displaying the elements below the images

Comment: I know what you want, but you can't use `position: absolute` on the images. This won't work. You should edit the snippet in the question to add your slideshow functionality. This will help you get answers to your question.

Comment: This snippet is just a basic example to show what is not working. The slideshow per se, is not the issue. I just need to get this part to work first

Comment: Here's the problem: **we** need more to help **you**. You may think the slideshow is not the issue, but with a little more code and context, we could offer a solution for your slideshow (since the images in the slideshow are causing your issue). How does the slideshow work? Does it only show one image at a time? With that information - you may not have to use `position: absolute`.

Comment: I just want all the images to be at top 0 and left 0 inside the parent element so as to fade in or out to the next image and of course, it should be responsive.

Comment: Manage to find a working solution by including each  img in a parent element and applying absolute position to that element, then setting the img to a width and height of 100% + using object-fit.

Answer (score 1):

Found a  trick to fix my issue with a working solution. I added a **position: relative** dummy  img with the same size of the other images.
Here's a working fully responsive  example with only 2 images in the slideshow

```
<style>
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.slideshow {
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.images img {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
inset: 0;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 1200ms ease-in-out;
}

.dummy {
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height: auto;
opacity: 0;
}

.active{
opacity: 1 !important;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>The Header</h1>
<section>
<div class="slideshow">

<img class="dummy" src="imagedummy.png" alt="">

<div class="images" id="images">
<!-- image size 1200 × 550 -->
<img class="active" src="image1.png" alt="">
<img src="image2.png" alt="">
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<hr>
<H1>New section</H1>
</section>
</div>
</body>

<script>
const images = document.getElementById("images").children
function showNext(){
for (child of images ) {
if (child.classList.contains("active")) 
child.classList.remove("active")
else
child.classList.add("active")
};
}
setInterval( () => {showNext()}, 4000 )

</script>
<body>
```